# Zsh - What is $~variable expansion called and is it different from $~==variable?

Tags: zsh

I found this sudo wrapper from [Zsh mailing list](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg01229.html):

```sh
alias sudo='noglob do_sudo '
function do_sudo
{
    integer glob=1
    local -a run
    run=( command sudo )
    if [[ $# -gt 1 && $1 = -u ]]; then
        run+=($1 $2)
        shift ; shift
    fi
    (($# == 0)) && 1=/bin/zsh
    while (($#)); do
        case "$1" in
        command|exec|-) shift; break ;;
        nocorrect) shift ;;
        noglob) glob=0; shift ;;
        *) break ;;
        esac
    done
    if ((glob)); then
        PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" $run $~==*
    else
        PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" $run $==*
    fi
}
```

It uses `$~==*` to expand the file patterns. What is this kind of expansion called? Where is it documented? (really have got no idea how to search for this, 'dollar tilde expansion', 'filename expansion', 'tilde expansion' all just gave me some irrelevant results...)

And I noticed that actually `$~var` also works, e.g.

```sh
$ touch foo bar
$ t1='fo*'
$ echo $~t1
foo
$ t2=('fo*' 'ba*')
$ echo $~t2
foo bar
```

Is it any different from `$~==t1`? Btw it seems there can be an arbitrary number of `=`s between `$` and variable name, `$~=t1` `$=~t1` `$~=====t1` all look the same.

Comment: See `man zshexpn` for the explanation of `${~spec}`.

Comment: @chepner Cool! And ${=spec} is just above it. Could you put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. I wasn't bright enough to recognize that `~` and `==` stacked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner for the hint. Here's what I found in `zshexpn` manual:

```
${=spec}
      Perform  word  splitting  using  the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during the evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the parameter appears in double quotes; if the `=' is
      doubled, turn it off.  This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words before substitution, using IFS as a delimiter.  This is done  by  default  in  most
      other shells.

      Note that splitting is applied to word in the assignment forms of spec before the assignment to name is performed.  This affects the result of array assignments with the A
      flag.

${~spec}
      Turn on the GLOB_SUBST option for the evaluation of spec; if the `~' is doubled, turn it off.  When this option is set, the string resulting from the expansion will be in‐
      terpreted  as  a pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of the `='
      and `!=' operators in conditions.

      In nested substitutions, note that the effect of the ~ applies to the result of the current level of substitution.  A surrounding pattern operation on the result may  can‐
      cel  it.   Hence,  for  example,  if  the  parameter  foo is set to *, ${~foo//\*/*.c} is substituted by the pattern *.c, which may be expanded by filename generation, but
      ${${~foo}//\*/*.c} substitutes to the string *.c, which will not be further expanded.
```

So `~` enables globbing which substitutes patterns (specs) with file names. `==` makes sure that word splitting is disabled for strings in quotes.

For example:

```sh
$ touch foo bar
$ spec='fo* ba*'
$ echo $~spec
zsh: no matches found: fo* ba*
$ echo $~=spec
foo bar
$ echo $~==spec
zsh: no matches found: fo* ba*
$ function test1() { printf '1=%s 2=%s\n' $1 $2; }
$ test1 $spec
1=fo* ba* 2=
$ test1 $~spec
zsh: no matches found: fo* ba*
$ test1 $~=spec
1=foo 2=bar
$ test1 $~==spec
zsh: no matches found: fo* ba*
$ test1 $=spec
1=fo* 2=ba*
```